# How to avoid unnecessary looping when passing variables from one function to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

As requested im posting part of  actual code, my intention is to learn and practice programming on the example of constructing sudoku squares, most of the code has been omitted but this below should be runnable and represents my problem. Since the code is allready here ill happily take suggestions about improving anything but main question is still how to avoid loopin unnecessarily:

```
from random import shuffle
#for brevity ill omit how i got to this point
sudoku =[6,1,9,3,2,8,5,4,7,2,5,7,6,9,4,3,1,8,4,3,8,7,1,5,2,6,9,5,8,6,1,4,
          3,9,7,2,3,9,1,2,8,7,6,5,4,7,4,2,9,5,6,1,8,3,None,None,None,None,
          None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,
          None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None]

#provides args for list indexing to help satisfy sudoku sub-square rule
sq_pos = [(0, 1, 2, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19, 20),
          (3, 4, 5, 12, 13, 14, 21, 22, 23),
          (6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26),
          (27, 28, 29, 36, 37, 38, 45, 46, 47),
          (30, 31, 32, 39, 40, 41, 48, 49, 50),
          (33, 34, 35, 42, 43, 44, 51, 52, 53),
          (54, 55, 56, 63, 64, 65, 72, 73, 74),
          (57, 58, 59, 66, 67, 68, 75, 76, 77),
          (60, 61, 62, 69, 70, 71, 78, 79, 80)]

#this function finds allowed numbers for each column
def lastColumnsPossibilities(slist, n_of_square):
    poss_col = []
    print('in lastColumnsPossibilities')
    for j in range(n_of_square*3, 3*n_of_square + 3):
        col = []
        pcol = []
        for i in range(j, j + 46, 9):
            col.append(slist[i])
        for k in range(1,10):                
            if k not in col:
                pcol.append(k)
        poss_col.append(pcol)
    return poss_col

#this function uses allowed numbers output by previous one
def lastSquareFill(slist, n_of_square, ff, fs, ft, 
                   sf, ss, st, tf, ts, tt):
    poss_col = lastColumnsPossibilities(slist, n_of_square)
    plist = poss_col[0]
    shuffle(plist)
    slist[ff] = plist.pop()
    slist[sf] = plist.pop()
    slist[tf] = plist.pop()
    dlist = poss_col[1]
    shuffle(dlist)
    slist[fs] = dlist.pop()
    slist[ss] = dlist.pop()
    slist[ts] = dlist.pop()
    tlist = poss_col[2]
    shuffle(tlist)
    slist[ft] = tlist.pop()
    slist[st] = tlist.pop()
    slist[tt] = tlist.pop()

#this function provides condition according to sudoku rules
def checkRow(slist, rn):
    row = []
    for i in range(rn * 9, rn * 9 + 9):
        row.append(slist[i])
    if len(set(row)) == 9:
        return True
    else:
        return False

#my actual loop is ofc longer, but instead of posting everything i 
#provided list sudoku that is 2/3 filled
def testLoop(slist):
    print('test')
    while (checkRow(slist, 6) != True
           or checkRow(slist, 7) != True
           or checkRow(slist, 8) != True):
        print('loop')
        lastSquareFill(sudoku, 0, *sq_pos[6])
        lastSquareFill(sudoku, 1, *sq_pos[7])
        lastSquareFill(sudoku, 2, *sq_pos[8])

testLoop(sudoku)
```

output i get is:

```
loop
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities 
loop
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities   #this repeats over and over
```

output i want would be:

```
loop
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities 
loop
loop                         #only loop till solution is found
```

My original question was and still is how to not do the useless cycling without introducing new global variables (which is a bad practice i ve been told). As a beginner ill gladly accept any other advice considering my code and my questions posting. Sorry for previously bad question, its my first one...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], without these substitutions. We can't run this, nor do we know what logic you're using in the abbreviated parts.

Comment: You said that each call to `b()` uses different `arg` and `*args`. Doesn't that mean that you're calling `a()` with different `arg`? So you can't reuse the value of `var`, because it could be different each time.

Comment: ill repost question with my code trimmed down which will take me a few hours. thanks for suggestions and replies.

Comment: @barmar that is exactly part of my problem, i have different values of var to pass to b() and that requires a() to be executed with according parametrs. In other words it would require at least 3 global variables to store returns without calling a() in the loop, unless i find better way. (i am under impression global variables are badf practice)

Comment: Can you use a dict to store the different values, so you can look it up based on an input?

Comment: Is each call to `b` in the loop different for just the 3 calls or every iteration? So two loops is 6 calls with 3 different or 6 calls with all 6 different?

Comment: @ aryamccarthy i hope after edit question is better, if i should improve anything else pls let me know, i for sure wouldnt wish to drag down quality of this site

Comment: @Barmar if i dont find a better soluition i will use a dict but where would you suggest i declare it first?

Comment: It probably has to be a global variable. Or you could define a class, then it could be a class property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the question edit it really clarifies the issue at hand, so I believe this is what you are after.

I modified `lastSquareFill` to take `poss_col` removing the call to it instead.

```
def lastSquareFill(slist, n_of_square, poss_col, ff, fs, ft, 
                   sf, ss, st, tf, ts, tt):
    plist = poss_col[0]
    shuffle(plist)
    ...
```

I then moved the call to outside the while loop creating a list of each `lastColumnsPossibilities`, you could also have a variable for each one, but I find this cleaner.

```
# Variable for each
lcp0 = lastColumnsPossibilities(sudoku, 0)
lcp1 = lastColumnsPossibilities(sudoku, 1)
...
```

---

```
def testLoop(slist):
    print('test')
    # Create list of each lastColumnsPossibilities
    # range(3) is used to match the 3 calls, but you will likely have 9 for sudoku
    lcp = [lastColumnsPossibilities(sudoku, i) for i in range(3)]
    while (checkRow(slist, 6) != True
           or checkRow(slist, 7) != True
           or checkRow(slist, 8) != True):
        print('loop')
        lastSquareFill(sudoku, 0, lcp[0], *sq_pos[6])
        lastSquareFill(sudoku, 1, lcp[1], *sq_pos[7])
        lastSquareFill(sudoku, 2, lcp[2], *sq_pos[8])
```

---

This produces the following output,

```
test
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities
loop
loop
```

---

If however you want it to enter the loop first to avoid processing without the check then you can use a dict (list can still work but a dict would be more optimal)

```
def lastSquareFill(slist, n_of_square, lcp, ff, fs, ft, 
                   sf, ss, st, tf, ts, tt):


    # if they don't exist create them and add to the dict
    if n_of_square not in lcp:      
        lcp[n_of_square] = lastColumnsPossibilities(slist, n_of_square)

    poss_col = lcp[n_of_square]
    plist = poss_col[0]
    shuffle(plist)
    ...

def testLoop(slist):
    print('test')
    lcp = {} # dict to hold all the lastColumnsPossibilities mapped to the square number
    while (checkRow(slist, 6) != True
           or checkRow(slist, 7) != True
           or checkRow(slist, 8) != True):
        print('loop')
        lastSquareFill(sudoku, 0, lcp, *sq_pos[6])
        lastSquareFill(sudoku, 1, lcp, *sq_pos[7])
        lastSquareFill(sudoku, 2, lcp, *sq_pos[8])
```

Which then gives

```
test
loop
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities
in lastColumnsPossibilities
loop
```

---

**Update:**

In `lastSquareFill` you need to take a copy `[:]` of the list so that it doesn't affect the original list when you pop the values.

```
# make a copy instead
plist = poss_col[0][:] 
dlist = poss_col[1][:]
tlist = poss_col[2][:]
```

Comment: I modified lastSquareFill to take poss_col then declared lcp = [lastColumnsPossibilities(sudoku, i) for i in range(3)] but then i got IndexError: pop from empty list. After examination i saw that lastSquareFill  empties the poss_col even thou it it does plist.pop(). Could it be that instead of instancing new list (plist) it just ''moves pointer'' to poss_col[0] and then pops from there leaving me without arguments for next loop? Could i have done something wrong on this simple modification?

Comment: No, that is what happens whenever you pop from it. You will instead need to keep making a copy of it then in `lastSquareFill`. I'll update answer.

Comment: It works and now instead of recalculating the value in the loop i just copy it which is much more efficient. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It is rather difficult to understand what your code is doing because so much of it is replaced with unhelpfully vague comments. Nonetheless -

In your 'sub-optimal' solution, you're passing `a` as an argument to `b` just so you can call `a` within the function and assign its returned value to the local variable `var`. This is terribly inefficient, especially since you say the value `a` returns doesn't change. A solution that avoids global variables would be:

```
def a(list, arg):
    return another_list

def b(_list, arg, a_value, *args):
    # Your code here #
    return _list

def Main(list): 
    while some_function():
        var=a(_list, arg)
        b(_list, arg, var, *args)
        b(_list, arg, var, *args)
        b(_list, arg, var, *args)
```

Comment: I tried this already however a is still being called from inside the loop and running over and over unnecessarly. Sorry for unprecise question and thanks for your reply, i will most likly delete this and trim my code down then paste it so people can run it and evaluate it accordingly.

Comment: @codeprimate123 But now it's only being called once per loop, not 3 times per loop.

Comment: @Barmar i need 3 different vars so it has to be like:   var1=a(list, arg1); var2=a(list, arg2); var3=a(list, arg3) eventually it gets called 3 times per loop

Comment: @codeprimate123 Don't put clarifications in the comments, edit the question so we can understand what you're really doing. It's very confusing right now.